# In the medical field what terminology do they use in describe cures and treatments

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, terminology

When doctors diagnose a poison what are the treatments cures called to stop the poison? What other names to the cures and treatment are there?

Comment: Would antidote be a good one? Or antivenom or maybe antiserum? Which fits the best in the medical field?

Answer (score 1):

There may be an **Antidote** to a poison.

Not so much a 'cure', more something to counteract the effects of the poison.

Comment: Antidote is not term for treatment. It is a medicine given to prevent spreading of poison. Also, please include standard definition from standard dictionaries. I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I write a good answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) It will help you trailer your answer/explantion prudently. Remember, healthy answer attracts healthy responses.

Answer (score 1):

**"Treatment of poisoning"** is the general term. Depending on whether poisoning is due to inhaling, touching, swallowing, or injecting chemicals, gases, animal venoms, etc, there are specific guidelines for each one of them, which may include:

- in situ first-aid
- antidote administration
- dyalisis
- gastric lavage
- symptomatic treatment
- life support measures
- in-hospital observation
- etc.

Still, the general term is **"treatment of poisoning"** but you can be more specific by saying **"treatment of ivy poisoning"**, **"treatment of snakebite poisoning"**, etc.

The study and practice of the symptoms, mechanisms, diagnosis, and treatment of poisoning is called "toxicology". from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning)